# Login issues appears when moving from java 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java

I have a server program and a user interface program run on different computers.

All works fine when using the 1.6 jvm but when i put 1.7 or 1.8 on the client machine the user interface program cannot log in
The program runs in as much as it will load the login screen but the log just shows that it retries a few times then gives the login failed message.

ERROR: 2015-01-13 14:42:52,195 [com..delegator.UserLoginDelegator.login] server connection lost
java.rmi.RemoteException: could not connect to server

```
    at com.delegator.UserLoginDelegator.login(UserLoginDelegtor.java:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.server.ConnectionRetryInvocation.invoke(ConnectioRetryInvocation.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.keyconsole.UserLogin.login(UserLogin.java:55)
    at com.keyconsole.Loginnested.OK_actionPerformed(Loginneted.java:415)
    at com.keyconsole.Loginnested.actionPerformed(Loginneste.java:376)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Souce)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the error message in the log if it helps.

I have tried compiling the user interface with the 1.6 and 1.7 jdk but it makes no difference.

How can i go about debugging this version mismatch issue, iv never faced a problem like it

Comment: Where is the **full stacktrace** of the error?

Comment: Only that, there's no inner cause or something else? Apart from that, looks more like a connection issue, non Java related.

Comment: Have you tried running with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza maybe it is but why does it work perfectly on the same machine with 1.6 and not with 1.7 ?